Enabling the meta database
Will Enabling the meta database also allow for joining multiple datasets in SuperSet?
I'd like to join 2 existing SuperSet datasets. Is that functionality available?
My organization is considering enabling meta database to join data from multiple database, but the person researching also thought taking this action would also allow for joining multiple SuperSet datasets to create a separate dataset.
